# How to sort in Laravel with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I want to sort this data by category name. this is my sample table

[image: 1]

this is sample data:

[image: 2]

this is the output and my expected output:

[image: 3]

Comment: Can you show us the code you're running which generated your current output?

Comment: $allItems = Item::with(['categoryItems' => function($q1){
                                $q1->with(['category' => function ($query) { return $query->orderBy('name','DESC'); }]);
                            },
                        ]);

Comment: In your expected output, I understand you want to sort by category name when you're within the same item, but you're also messing up the order of the items from `Sample Name 1, Sample Name 2, Sample Name 3` to `Sample Name 1, Sample Name 3, Sample Name 2`. Is there any logic to this order or would you prefer to order by item name then by category name?

Comment: thats a nice idea but i want to try to sort by categoryname nevermind the item name.. i want to see all the sorted category inside the items.. by the way thank you so much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and it seems nested eager loading creates another query using `IN`. It isn't a join so you can't reference the previous query. Thus the `name` would refer to the category but it would be matched up 1:1 with the pivot table and thus this orderBy will be useless since it would use the categoryItems ordering following the `IN`.

It seems you need to do a join in order to be able to orderBy at the pivot table level where the category order would matter, but you wouldn't have the category.name available at that level either.

Unless of course you had a join.

Thus if you decided to use a join, it would look something like this:

```
$allItems = Item::with(['categoryItems' => function($q1){
    // Note: Categories here is a reference to the table name not the model.
    $q1->join('Categories','category_id','=','categories.id')
    ->orderBy('name','ASC');
}]);

$allItems = $items->get();

foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    echo $item->name.':<br>';
    foreach($item['categoryItems'] as $cat) {
        echo "- {$cat['name']}<br>";
    }
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Note that the outer query can also use an orderBy so you can do things like this too:

```
$items = Item::with(['categoryItems' => function($q1){
    $q1->join('Categories','category_id','=','categories.id')
    ->orderBy('name','DESC'); // name here is the cat name
}])->orderBy('name','DESC'); // name here is the item name
```